# Error: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a class like this:

```
public class Questionnaire {

    private String         questionnaireLibelle;
    private List<Question> questions;
    // ...

}
```

And I've initialized a new Questionnaire like this:

```
Questionnaire q = new Questionnaire(
                "Architecture des ordinateurs",
                Arrays.asList(
                    new Question( "1. La partie du processeur spécialisée pour les calculs est :"),
                    new Question("2. Dans un ordinateur, les données sont présentées par un signal électrique de la forme :"),
                    new Question("3. Les différents éléments d’un ordinateur (mémoire, processeur, périphériques…) sont reliés entre eux par des:")
                )
        );
```

As you see I used `Arrays.asList()` instead of declaring a new `ArrayList`.

In another class I used this code:

```
for(Question q : (ArrayList<Question>) request.getAttribute("listQuestions"))
```

But I got this error for that line:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened because you used the concrete type in your cast.  Try just this:

```
for(Question q : (List<Question>) request.getAttribute("listQuestions"))
```

Since you have the guarantee that it uses the interface.  As a style guide, always prefer the use of the interface to concrete types.

Comment: I'm not doing exactly the same thing but your point is correct, is just an inheritance stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to cast, just iterate over `request.getAttribute("listQuestions")`, the `List` implementation returned by `Arrays.asList`, and all `Collections` instances, are implementations of 'Iterable' and you can use then in `for(... in ...)`.

More: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

Answer (score 1):

The [return type of the `Arrays.asList(...)` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) is a `List<T>`. Therefore you **must not** make any assumptions about the concrete type of the class used to implement the [`List` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Internally any kind of list could be used by Arrays.asList. Of course one might expect that an ArrayList is used here, but this could be changed with every Java version.

I guess what you want is closer to this (I simplified a bit):

```
public class Questionnaire {

    private String         questionnaireLibelle;
    private List<Question> questions;

    public List<Question> getQuestions() { return questions; }
.....
}
```

And then:

```
for(Question q : request.getQuestions()) { ... }
```