# Code runs but gives me java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, exception, arraylist

I'm doing a beginner Java tutorial on ArrayList that asks me to do the below

```
// Create a method called removeOdd
    // Remove all the odd numbers from an ArrayList 

    // removeOdd(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21)) => {2, 8}
    // removeOdd(Arrays.asList(7,34,2,3,4,62,3)) => {34, 2, 4, 62}
```

The below is my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Ex4_RemoveOdd {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        removeOdd((ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21));
        removeOdd((ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(7,34,2,3,4,62,3));
    }

    public static void removeOdd(ArrayList<Integer> list){
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            int num = list.get(i);
            if (num % 2 != 0){
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

The code runs, but gives me the below error code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

I understand there is another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21827863/java-util-arraysarraylist-cannot-be-cast-to-java-util-arraylist) on SO

However I kind of think our situations are different since the OP did not declare a list within a method using AsList like I did.

Thanks so much for your time :)

Comment: What you did wrong: not read the api documentation of Arrays.asList(). Does it say it returns an ArrayList? Does it say that the returned list has a variable size? Everything becomes easier, and you learn a lot, when you read the documentation.

Comment: I wonder whether System.out.println(list) would output anything meaningful here.

Comment: Also, even if you don't cast and return a List<Integer>, you'll get an UnsupportedOperationException if you try to remove a value from a fixed array (hint: don't use Arrays.asList for this task)

Comment: @ValentinRuano well I fixed the code and `System.out.println(list)` does print meaningful output in my case. I get `[2, 5, 8, 21]` for my first run of the `removeOdd` method

Comment: @JBNizet @spudone yea the problem is that the question itself told me to use `removeOdd(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21))`, so as a beginner I got confused between what the api  was saying and what the question was saying :/

That being said, I'll make sure to trust the API more than the question in the future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [`Arrays.asList` returns a `List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-), but it's not `java.util.ArrayList`.  It's a `private` nested class `ArrayList`, nested inside `Arrays`, and it's different.  It doesn't support addition or removal of the generated list.

To make an actual `java.util.ArrayList`, pass the `List` to the proper [`ArrayList` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-), that takes a `Collection`, e.g.

```
removeOdd(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21)));
```

As for why the inner class is referred to as `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList`, that is because the the dollar sign `$` separates the enclosing class name from the nested class name.

Comment: (Why it was called `ArrayList` instead of something more fitting and less name-clashing .. but it is what it is.)

Comment: @user2864740 Because it is also List which internally uses array as container for elements. But I agree name could be better.

Comment: @user2864740 They are both List(s) which wrap arrays. One class is called `Arrays$ArrayList` so it is not easily confused with `ArrayList`

Comment: To me, `..$ArrayList` seems pretty close to `ArrayList` - and I doubt such has reduced the OPs confusion. If it were `Arrays$ArrayWrapperList` I would clearly go, "wait, uh what?!?"

Comment: @user2864740 the name of the class is `Arrays$ArrayList`, not `ArrayList`, so they're clearly not the same. Period.

Comment: @user2864740 I would go with something like `ArrayWrappingList`, because `ArrayWrapperList` feels more like `Wrapper` for `ArrayList` (which may also be confusing) but I don't remember seeing any class names with `...ing` part, so I suspect such name could be also considered as bad.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know what I did wrong?

There are two classes called `ArrayList` one you can use directly and one you shouldn't.  You can't cast one to the other just because they happen to have the same name.

Fortunately you don't need to be doing this in the first place as you don't need to specify that an ArrayList is required.  You can write it such that any mutable list can be passed.  BTW Arras.aslIst is a fixed length so you can't use it here.

Instead I would suggest not altering you list but rather printing the result.

```
printEven(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21));
printEven(Arrays.asList(7,34,2,3,4,62,3));

public static void removeOdd(Iterable<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<>();
    for (integer i: list) if (i %2 == ) even.add(i);
    System.out.println(even);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
removeOdd((ArrayList<Integer>) Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21));
```

An `ArrayList` **is not** the same as the `List` returned by `Arrays#asList`, and the stacktrace is telling you:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList **cannot be cast to** java.util.ArrayList

Create a new `ArrayList` and pass the `List` returned from `Arrays#asList` as argument:

```
removeOdd(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,8,13,21)));
```